# two condition in two different row pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to define the state between two rows and two column in pandas

```
              Open Time   Close    shortEMA     longEMA   Buy  Sell
1 2020-12-23 11:49:00  598.76  598.651908  598.902220   NaN   NaN
2 2020-12-23 11:50:00  598.61  599.637938  598.875654   NaN   NaN  if (shortEMA > longEMA)
3 2020-12-23 11:51:00  598.13  597.468626  598.807868   NaN   NaN  and (shortEMA < longEMA) Buy = Close
```

I try some thing like this but must have some issue with to get condition from two row i thing:

```
data.loc[(data['shortEMA'][-1:] < data['longEMA'][-1:]) & (data['shortEMA'] > data['longEMA']), 'Buy'] = data['Close']
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: put to column buy number from close column if condition

Comment: I mean how the dataframe would look like.

Comment: same like what i post just not have on right side if condition

Comment: like this work data.loc[(data['shortEMA'] > data['longEMA']), 'Buy'] = data['Close'] work but i want add condition from before row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your current code, but in order to reference the previous row you needed to shift it downwards first.

For a cleaner solution, we can build a simple boolean condition using `shift` and `eval`:

```
m = df.shift().eval('shortEMA > longEMA') & df.eval('shortEMA < longEMA')
df.loc[m, 'Buy'] = df['Close']

df
         Open      Time   Close    shortEMA     longEMA     Buy  Sell
1  2020-12-23  11:49:00  598.76  598.651908  598.902220     NaN   NaN
2  2020-12-23  11:50:00  598.61  599.637938  598.875654     NaN   NaN
3  2020-12-23  11:51:00  598.13  597.468626  598.807868  598.13   NaN
```

---

Or, as a one liner using `np.where`:

```
df['Buy'] = np.where(
    df.shift().eval('shortEMA > longEMA') & df.eval('shortEMA < longEMA'),
    df['Close'],
    np.nan)

df
         Open      Time   Close    shortEMA     longEMA     Buy  Sell
1  2020-12-23  11:49:00  598.76  598.651908  598.902220     NaN   NaN
2  2020-12-23  11:50:00  598.61  599.637938  598.875654     NaN   NaN
3  2020-12-23  11:51:00  598.13  597.468626  598.807868  598.13   NaN
```